# JQuery Object to String (with Object elements) and write it into cookie

Tags: jquery, string, object, cookies

I have a list with some images in it,
want to reorder the list elements (which works fine with sortable jquery ui) and then write the scr of the images into a cookie in the right order.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
         cursor: "move",
         update: function() { 

        var reordered = $('#sortable li img').each(function(index, value){
                        console.log = ($(this).attr('src'));
                        }); 

        cookie.set('pdfbilder', reordered, {
        duration : 1,
        path : '/',
        secure : false
        });

         }
```

I understand that console.log is just to check the output and this works, but the "reordered" variable and so the cookie value is [object Object]

I really searched and tried but couldn't find a solution for this...
(to be honest, i'm quite new with jquery)
Anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `map()` to iterate through the elements matched by the selector, returning a property of the 'currently-iterated-over' node/object `this.src` (`$(this).attr('src')` is unnecessarily expensive) and then forming an array of those returned properties and joining them together to form a string, using `join()`:

```
var reordered = $('#sortable li img')
                    .map(function(){ return this.src; })
                    .get().join(' ');
```

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t2QFC/).

Without a delimiter passed to the `join()` method, it defaults to a comma-separated string; in the given code sample I've chosen to use a single white-space character instead, but amend as you see fit.

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: @johnSmith: do you? It doesn't.